# How to generate the random values of map from a given set of values and then store the key and values into separate variables in scala

Tags: list, scala, random

I am trying to generate the 1000 random key-val map pairs from the given(statically defined) 2 map key-val pairs in scala and also later i would want to break the key and value pairs and store them into separate variables

Whatever i have tried:

```
object methodTest extends App{

  val testMap = Map("3875835"->"ABCDE","316067107"->"EFGHI")
  def getRandomElement(seq: Map[String,String]): Map[String,String] = {

    seq(Random.nextInt(seq.length))
  } 
 var outList = List.empty[Map[String,String]]
 for(i<-0 to 1000){
   outList+=getRandomElement(testMap)
 }
 print(outList)
}
```

The Output should generate 1000 Key-val pairs of map like i am showing below

```
[3875835,ABCDE]
[316067107,EFGHI]
[3875835,ABCDE]
[316067107,EFGHI]
[316067107,EFGHI]
............
............
............. upto 1000 random key-val pairs
```

Please help me figure out where i am going wrong and let me know How to resolve it, if any issue regarding the requirement, please feel free to comment for it

Comment: I am not sure I understand what should be random according to your expected output. Should you generate 1000 random numbers for each entry in `testMap`? Or 1000 in total? Should the value be constant? Please fix your expected output to be randomised. It will be clearer to understand what you are asking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can transform your seed map `testMap` into sequence of key/value [tuples](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/tuples.html) using `.toSeq` and then generate key/value pairs by iterating over the list of numbers from 0 until 1000, associating each number to a random choice between first or second element of the seed:

```scala
import scala.util.Random

val testMap = Map("3875835" -> "ABCDE", "316067107" -> "EFGHI")

val seed = testMap.toSeq
val keyValuesList = (0 until 1000).map(index => seed(Random.nextInt(seed.size)))
```

*Note: `0 until 1000` will return all the numbers from 0 to 1000 excluded, so 1000 numbers. If you use `0 to 1000` you will get all the numbers from 0 to 1000 included, so 1001 numbers.*

If you want to print the resulting list, you can use `.foreach` method with `println` function as argument:

```scala
keyValuesList.foreach(println)
```

And you will get:

```
(3875835,ABCDE)
(316067107,EFGHI)
(3875835,ABCDE)
(3875835,ABCDE)
(316067107,EFGHI)
(3875835,ABCDE)
...
```

if you want to keep only the keys, you can iterate on the list using `.map` method, taking only the first element of the tuple by using `._1` method, that retrieve the first element of a tuple:

```scala
val keys = keyValuesList.map(keyValuePair => keyValuePair._1)
```

And if you want only a list containing all second elements of each pair:

```scala
val values = keyValuesList.map(keyValuePair => keyValuePair._2)
```